# What is the scope of C programming today?

Tags: c

I am a computer science student. I studied C, then came to C++[an object oriented one] and now Java[More Object Oriented]. My question is whether 'C' language is of any importance these days? Did I study it for the sake of studying the languages in the order in  which they were developed so as to understand languages step by step?

Is there things that can be done only with C? What is it's scope?

Comment: What about some research? E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#Uses. And why is Java more object oriented than C++ (and what should this even mean)?

Comment: While C is still widely used in many applications this question is primarily opinion based and has no definitive answer.  I suggest reddit, slashdot or maybe one of the SO chat rooms is a better forum than Stackoverflow for this type of dicussion.

Comment: C is often used for firmware and OS development and where performance is critical. C++ is a heavier language and Java almost always requires a VM.

Comment: I am a firmware engineer and program primarily in C.

Comment: The simple fact of the matter is this: C, like it or not, is still with us. It is the language of choice for low-level programming. Kernels, drivers, embedded systems... a lot of them are programmed in C. This will probably remain the case for some time. But C has other use-cases that are worth noting: games are developed in a variety of languages. And it's not uncommon for some internal components to be written in C or even pure assembly. Small desktop applications are relatively easy to write in C, if you know your way around libs like GTK+

Comment: the interpreters of many scripting languages are written in C, too: PHP, Perl, Python, some/parts of JavaScript engines... a lot of the GNU tools we all use every day were written in C, too. While it is true that C is not the default go-to language, it is still relevant today. No matter what anybody tries to tell you. Objective-C, the language apple swears by, is C with classes. It's a superset of C. Not a very good one, but no matter

Comment: It sounds like, they introduced programming concepts step by step, C++ & Java have large libraries, whilst the standard C library is small.  It's a touch perverse to go C -> Java, more students start with Java or Python or C++, then take a low level Systems programming in C course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main scopes are:

- drivers
- operating systems
- systems where performance is critical
- small embedded systems (thanks Joachim)

Comment: Also small embedded systems.

Comment: And anything with very strict timing requirements, not just overall performance/throughput. DSP, audio, and video processing, for example.

Comment: And C tends to lead to less recompiling (less inlining or leaking of fancy datastructures which need special care to avoid keeping privacy of implentation details), nor does it encourage over-abstraction or over-engineering of Interface design.  Most good std C programs, recompile as C++ with only very minor changes (cast of void * to other ptr type, which C++ bitches about otherwise).

Comment: But C++ is a larger more fully featured language with larger standard library and emphasises type safety of programs.  Unfortunately as any in depth article on C++ features will show, there's a lot of subtle complexity and room for gotchas with added features.  C++'s abstract class support and generic programming are the key benefits in my mind.  Both C/C++ and most computer languages are Turing complete, therefore any computable problem may be computed in them.  It's just easier if you pick the right language for the job :)

Answer (score 4):

C is still heavily used in situations where otherwise one would drop down to assembler, since it's one of the few structured languages to let users code that close to the hardware.

And a lot of what claims to be C++ code is C code with an OOP wrapper.